# Acting on job failure with ActiveJob and DelayedJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, rails-activejob

My Rails application is using ActiveJob + DelayedJob to execute some background jobs.

I am trying to figure out what is the way to define what happens on failure (not on error) - meaning, if DelayedJob has marked the job as failed, after the allowed 3 attempts, I want to perform some operation.

This is what I know so far:

1. DelayedJob has the aptly named [`failure` hook](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#hooks).
2. This hook is [not supported in ActiveJob](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/30205)
3. ActiveJob has a [`rescue_from` method](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#exceptions)
4. The `rescue_from` method is probably not the right solution, since I do not want to do something on *each* exception, but rather only after 3 attempts (read: only after DelayedJob has deemed the job as failed).
5. ActiveJob has an [`after_perform` hook](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_perform), which I cannot utilize since (as far as I can see) it is not called when `perform` fails.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried looking at attemps value on database on failure? like on failure method, if attemps == 3, do something

Comment: There is no appropriate callback function for it to my knowledge, and even if there is, looking at the database for attempts seems a bit hackish since an appropriate callback should have the job object handy.

Comment: Well it doesn't need to be a database call, on failure you have the job object right? I am not in home at the moment, but will make some tests later. It's not a specific callback for your need, but a simple validation on failure like if attempt == 3, do something it's not overkill if you have the object with the value there

Comment: If you want to discard the job, you can do it with https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Exceptions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-discard_on

Answer (score 0):

You may already find the solution to this, but for people who still struggle with this issue, you can use ActiveJob `retry_on` method with a block to run custom logic when maximum attempts have been reached but still failed.

```rb
class RemoteServiceJob < ApplicationJob
  retry_on(CustomAppException) do |job, error|
    ExceptionNotifier.caught(error)
  end
 
 
  def perform(*args)
    # Might raise CustomAppException
  end
end
```

You can find more info about Exception handling in `ActiveJob` in https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3.2/classes/ActiveJob/Exceptions/ClassMethods.html